# Add Index to All Elements of a List

Tags: list-manipulation, index

My goal is to add an index to all elements of a list in the form `{"a", "b", "c", ... }`, so it becomes `{"N1 a", "N2 b", "N3 c" ... }`, where the elements of the list are strings.

My current method is (sequence is a pre-defined list):

```
sequence = 
  Table[
    "N" <> ToString[i] <> " " <> ToString[sequence[[i]]], 
    {i, 1, Length[sequence]}];
```

I wonder if there's a more clever approach to this, since using `Table` seems like an overkill.

I can append a string to every element using:

```
sequence = 
  Replace[sequence, x_?StringQ :> "Test " <> ToString[x], All];
```

But here I don't know how to include the position/index of the elements, since they're not unique and I cannot use `Position` to determine their index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My goal is to add an index to all elements of a list in the form {"a",
>   "b", "c", ... }, so it becomes {"N1 a", "N2 b", "N3 c" ... }

may be

```
seq={"a","b","c","d"};
MapIndexed["N"<>ToString[First@#2]<>" "<>#1&,seq]
```

gives

```
{"N1 a", "N2 b", "N3 c", "N4 d"}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! Also, could you please explain what #1 and #2 are?

Comment: @Androvich The #2 gives the index of the entry. And the #1 gives the entry itself. Please see help on MapIndexed. Very useful function to know about !

Comment: Yeah, I looked into it and tried to play around with it, so it all makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

Array["N" <> ToString@# <> " " <> list[[#]] &, Length@list]
```

> {"N1 a", "N2 b", "N3 c", "N4 d"}